# Android - Unable to click button when using global exception

Tags: android, exception

I'm using global exception handler in my mainactivity and i've some buttons. If uncaught exception get called the button onclicklistener is not working.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
          @Override
          public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
              Log.e("Alert","Lets See if it Works !!!");

          }
      });
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphical_report);

    Button samBtn = findViewById(R.id.imggraphview);

    samBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

}

Error:

```
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:672)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:368)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:160)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:319)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at in.co.amiindia.vitalsservice.MessageTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:73)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at in.co.amiindia.vitalsservice.MessageTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:1)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
06-30 16:31:20.791: E/AndroidRuntime(2324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your onClick? and are you getting any error, if yes, then post stack trace.

Comment: any error are you getting?

Comment: I'm using one jar. From that jar i'm getting some error at that time uncaught exception getting called.

Comment: please show that error, and if your exception called then how your below code works?

Comment: Where is your this line in code?
at in.co.amiindia.vitalsservice.MessageTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:73)

Comment: That line is coming from jar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82032/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-kamal).

Answer (score 0):

set your view first.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphical_report);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
          @Override
          public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
              Log.e("Alert","Lets See if it Works !!!");

          }
      });
```

**And** Your button is not typecast.

Comment: Hi i tried still im facing same problem. I set the view first still button onclicklistener is not working

Comment: If error is not thrown button onclicklistener is working fine

Comment: Can you use click listener before uncaught exceptions.

Comment: I used click listener before uncaught exception still i'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cast A Button that might be a problem

```
Button samBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imggraphview);
```